# How can I prevent my application to not be turned off without admin permission?

Tags: python

I am working on a project named project.py.

I want to set an encryption on it, so that once it's finished and running only the admin can stop the program, and another user who isn't an admin using it can't terminate it. Even if the user closes the program, it will still continue to run in the background.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: This is more of an operating system question than a programming language one. And it doesn't really involve encryption.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Consult the documentation for the operating system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make it that only the admin can stop the program and another user who isn't an admin using it can't terminate it

just run your script under admin user, any other user who has no root/admin/superuser permissions won't be able to terminate process running under another user, operating system won't allow this.